# I am stuck on a question Algebra:Sequence and series, Can we make an infinitely long arithmetic progression from the set of prime integers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Today, I came across this question while learning sequence and series, the question is **Prove that we cannot make an infinite AP in the set of prime integers.**
I tried to solve it, but I couldn't proceed as there is no general formula for prime numbers so how can I prove that no infinite AP will be possible,
so I resorted to proving that any AP which has all terms prime integers will end at kth term.

I also consulted the Wikipedia article of **Green-Tao Theorem** 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem)
but I wasn't able to understand the solution present there.

I also saw some StackExchange answers but none answered my question or at least gave me a hint.

I also read this research paper http://academic.csuohio.edu/soprunov_i/pdf/primes.pdf

So I would request you to please guide me with a hint, not a solution.

Please note this is not my homework exercise, I am just learning algebra for my competitive examination preparation.

Comment: If the question has an issue please bring it to my notice, instead of down-voting, I will fix it as fast as I can

Comment: Think just a little bit about the first term and how the subsequent terms are expressed in terms of this and the common difference.

Comment: Think about a prime bigger than the common difference of your AP.

Comment: but how can we prove it for any first term

Comment: Hint: For any two integers $m < n$, $n! + m$ is divisible by $m$ and thus not prime.

Comment: @user8734617 Yes it is should I take it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of primes contains arbitrarily long APs by the Green-Tao theorem, but clearly no infinite AP. Assume that $p_0$ and $p_1$ are the first elements of such sequence and let $d=p_1-p_0$. $p_0+p_0 d=p_{p_0}$ is an element of such sequence but cannot be a prime, since it is a multiple of $p_0$.

Comment: AP is pn=p0+(n-1)d, this is wrong

Comment: @SkV: $p_n = p_0+ n d$. Notice that $p_1 = p_0 + 1 d$.